# exponential function for pythagoras tree?

Tags: exponential-function, fractals

the pythagoras tree is a fractal generated by squares. for each square, two new smaller squares are constructed and connected by their corners to the original square.

how do i create an exponential function to find out how many squares will be in the next sequence? since every iteration, the previous amount of squares added is doubled, how can i phrase this in function form? for example:

iteration 1: 0 + 1 = 1 square,

iteration 2: 1 + 1(2) = 3 squares,

iteration 3: 3 + 2(2) = 7 squares,

and so forth. sorry if this is a really easy question, but ive looked everywhere and tried a lot and cant find anything.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding $2^n$ squares in each iteration - this means that the next term ($n + 1$) has $2^{n + 1} - 1$ squares, as you have $2^{n} - 1$ squares till then, and $2^n + 2^{n} - 1 = 2^n \times 2 - 1 = 2^{n + 1} - 1$.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagoras_tree_(fractal)) has a nice diagram showing this process.